# The jumbotron is not displaying correctly when <!DOCTYPE html> is included

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, doctype

I've been building a simple website and realised that I've accidentally commented out `<!DOCTYPE html>` out. When I included it back, the jumbotron stopped displaying correctly - it is now shortened to about 1/10 of its height.

The CSS code which is:

```
.jumbotron {
    background-image: url("../images/up.jpg");
    background-size:cover;
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
}
```

Setting height to auto doesn't change anything. Setting the height to a value in pixels work, however I wanted to avoid doing this to make sure that it works well for all size screens.

I will be very grateful for you insights!

Comment: Set `html,body{height:100%;margin:0}` to ensure the document takes the full screen height.

Comment: Thanks - I've tried it but it doesn't seem to work...